# Question and the how to cut the angle of a 2x4 that is 109 inches long and 1 end is 3.5 down to 1.5

Tags: cutting, angle

Need to know what's the angle I need to rip down a 2x4 that 109 inches long from 3.5
down to 1.5

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to know the angle? Why not just mark a line on the board and then cut on the line?

But if you actually need the angle, that is basic geometry. Which plenty of websites help you calculate easily, such as [this Triangle Calculator found via Google](https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html):

- Angle A = 90
- Side b = 2 (3.5 - 1.5)
- Side c = 109

Clear the other values. Calculate. And you get Angle B = 88.949 and Angle C = 1.051 (90 - Angle B). Which, as expected, is a *very* shallow cut.